# How many connection can be created in jboss by default config?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, java-io

For http this config in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Its the default config.

I would like to know how many connections this server can handle both incoming and out going.

Like 3000 users(clients) and this server is communicating with other web services, so overall how many http/https connections can this handle at a time, also is there a way to find out the current number of connections

Comment: Maybe `acceptCount`? See here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-performance/jboss-performance-tuning-part-1?start=2 (not sure if it's still available in jboss 7)

Comment: Impossible to answer as it is fully determined by what the application does. (and the quality of the code, and the strength of the hardware, and the sanity of the network environment, etc. etc.)

Comment: @assylias there is no "acceptCount" in standalone.xml

Comment: @Gimby there should be a way to find out overall count I guess, not specific to application.

Comment: @Aadam Looks like it may now be fixed to 100: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202409?tstart=0